# CodeIgniter 2.0 upgrade - now links have "?" appended

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-2

I upgraded CI from 1.7.2 to 2.0.  It's "mostly" working, except all the links that are generated are putting a "?" after the base URL, but before the rest of the URL.

So what should be:

*www.site.com/aController*

Is being generated like:

*www.site.com/?aController*

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: FIXED: I had to set $config['enable_query_strings'] to FALSE in config.php...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `$config['enable_query_strings']` to `FALSE` in `config.php`.

This is covered along with all other random snags in my article:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0